# How can I pass symfony2 callback validator a parameter?

Tags: symfony

How can I pass symfony2 callback validator a parameter? I need to pass it a value from parameters ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link [Symfony2 - How to use Entity variables in CallbackValidator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9279666/1146363) directly address your question.  Basically the 'use' directive can pass variables:

```
    ->addValidator(new CallbackValidator(function($form) use($user)
```

However, when passing multiple arguments, I find it easier to just make a validator class that implements FormValidatorInterface and use it:

```
class UserNameValidator implements FormValidatorInterface
{
    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    public function validate(FormInterface $form)
    {
```

I'll even make it a service so I don't have to worry about constructing it.

Comment: I guess I assumed this was for a form.  You will need to create a custom constraint (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html). I have not made one so can't really help.